# Which one is responsible for the generation of http session ID? The client browser, the server, or both?

Tags: java, session, web

I am working on a Java web application which involves allocating server resources on a per http session basis. So the http session ID would become part of the key of a database table, and its uniqueness in the table is a must. The description of the Java `HttpSession.getID()` method claimed that this ID is unique, so the server side should have someway to enforce such nature. But on the client browser, HTTP session is usually shared by multiple browsing windows unless explicitly request a new session to be to used. This suggests that the browser have active control over session usage as well. So which side is responsible for the generation of HTTP session ID? Or it is a combined effort of both sides? Is there any chance that the same session ID is generated accidentally by browsers on different computers accessing the same website?

Comment: Client brewer generates beer rather than sessionIds?

Comment: SESSIONID is a cookie generated by Servlet container like Tomcat, it used for session management in J2EE web application for http protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session id is generated by server and is usually granted to a visitor on his/her first visit to a site.

> A session ID is a unique number that a Web site's server assigns a
>   specific user for the duration of that user's visit (session). The
>   session ID can be stored as a cookie, form field, or URL (Uniform
>   Resource Locator). Some Web servers generate session IDs by simply
>   incrementing static numbers. However, most servers use algorithms that
>   involve more complex methods, such as factoring in the date and time
>   of the visit along with other variables defined by the server
>   administrator.

Comment: If a session ID is generated by server, why is it shared by pages of  the same website? Is it because subsequent visit would have the session ID retrieved locally from the client PC rather than having the server generate it again?

Comment: @God_of_Thunder Yes, One more thing I ll like to mention is since you are going to store session in database and I don't have any idea how much you are going to rely on session ids but pay special attention to stuff like `random session attacks` and `session hijacking`